# System restarting after pressing scan on rootkit revealer

Tags: windows-xp, reboot, rootkit

My pc is affected with sality virus and after lot of investigation i could get to permanently enable regedit and taskmanager and clean infected files. But i wanted to remove it from the core so i used the rootkit revealer from sysinternals. However the system restarts the moment i click on th scan button, which i believe is done by th sality virus. How can i get to run the rootkit revealer on my machine? I even tried adding it to runOnce in registry but it fails there as well.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install Avast! Free, and schedule a boot time scan.

If this fails:
http://www.avast.com/bart-cd
[Bitdefender liveCD](http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/) (its free, I used this)

Comment: Thanks, i am trying kaspersky right now. Will try avast if this fails. Thanks